# Hi, how can I pass the user email and user name to other component after signing in with facebook or google login credentials

Tags: reactjs, firebase, state

how can I pass the user email and user name to other component  after signing in with facebook or google login credentials....after the signin in need to pass the name and email .. is there any need for extra functions ? any thoughts?

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import StyledFirebaseAuth from "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth";

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "dgshfjgkhlklgfhfjgjhgkhlfrfjgiE",
  authDomain: "fir-auth-6797445.firebaseapp.com"
})

class SocialLogin extends Component {
  state = { isSignedIn: false }

  uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: "popup",
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
       ],
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccess: () => false
    }
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ isSignedIn: !!user })

    })
  }

  render() {


    return (

      <div className="App">
        {this.state.isSignedIn ? (
            this.props.OnRouteChange('home')

            )
         : (
          <StyledFirebaseAuth
            uiConfig={this.uiConfig}
            firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SocialLogin
```

Comment: ` <StyledFirebaseAuth
            uiConfig={this.uiConfig}
            firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
          /> ` same as u passed the props here import the component u need the props

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass that data down to the other component. With Firebase you can access the currentUser object directly and its properties in any components inside your app.

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user != null) {
  user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
    console.log("Sign-in provider: " + profile.providerId);
    console.log("  Provider-specific UID: " + profile.uid);
    console.log("  Name: " + profile.displayName);
    console.log("  Email: " + profile.email);
    console.log("  Photo URL: " + profile.photoURL);
  });
}
```

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?hl=es-419#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information